# Why Jenkins creates @2 directory?

Tags: selenium, jenkins, testng

I'm using Jenkins to run my Selenium script to test my web applications. I'm quite new to Jenkins so it's a bit confusing to the Build now process. Because every time I do Build now for two job at the same time, second one creates `projectname...@2` at the end and looks for pom.xml file in the `@2` folder which is not containing the `pom.xml` file there.

Is there anyway to test my Selenium code without this build that creates `@2` folder?

Or simply run my Selenium code ONLY in Jenkins?

Comment: Did you try searching for an answer first? Or just simply think about the problem? You run two jobs at the same time. Each run needs a workspace on the node to run within. You don't want multiple jobs overwriting a common location, do you? [Documentation](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-durable-task-step/#ws-allocate-workspace). Or [`disableConcurrentBuilds()`](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#available-options).

Answer (score 0):

Before using `pom.xml` change the directory to where it is with environment parameter

```
script(){
dir ("${env.WORKSPACE}") { //change dir to where pom.xml is
  //run whatever
}}
```